# GCMRegistrar checkManifest crashses my app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have problems with GCMRegistrar, here is the code:

```
// Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this); <- this line is the problem (I suppose)
regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

When I change that line to a comment the app doesn't crash but the regId is empty, and when I try to use that line it makes my app crash, I don't know why so I hope you can help me. :)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.chattest1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.chattest1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.chattest1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.chattest1.RegisAct"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.chattest1.Main"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_regis" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. Also note that `GCMRegistrar` is officially deprecated -- Google requests that you start using `GoogleCloudMessaging` instead: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkManifest` checks if your manifest contains the definitions required for GCM to work.
It throws `IllegalStateException` when something is missing.

In your case, you are missing a broadcast receiver that can receive messages from GCM.

`GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this)` (which returns a locally stored registration ID) will return a non-empty value only if you call `GCMRegistrar.register` first. Note that `GCMRegistrar.register` is non-blocking, so the response doesn't arrive immediately.

Finally, as CommonsWare suggested, `GCMRegistrar` is deprecated and you are encouraged to use `GoogleClassMessaging` class instead.